# Container image name not transferred from the image itself

Tags: docker, pycharm

I run the command `docker build` with `-t` parameter in order to tag the image with the corresponding name.

When I do the `docker image ls`, I can see the corresponding image and the name that I used with the parameter `-t`. Nevertheless, when I run a container from that image, the `docker ps` command shows the new container, but the `IMAGE` column does not show the name that I have set for the image that this container has been created from. It shows IMAGE ID value instead of the IMAGE name, for e.g. `8a135cfa3821`.

I am using Pycharm 2018.1 to run the docker container. By running the container form this image through the command line, it works perfectly fine.

Photo below shows relevant columns for the output of the `docker ps -a` and `docker image ls` commands:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJwKA.png)

Comment: When you say "start a container", do you mean "`docker start`" an existing container, or "`docker run` a new one"?  Can you share the actual command line?

Comment: Can you please share screen-shot of 'docker ps -a' and 'docker images' command.

Comment: @DavidMaze, I mean running a new one.
So the problem is basically with the Pycharm. As I said: "By running the container form this image through the command line, it works perfectly fine."

Comment: @RohanJMohite, I updated my question with the screenshot. I am showing only relevant columns, I am unable to give you the screenshot because of the project's privacy terms.

Comment: That's useful; it sort of looks like pycharm is doing the equivalent of `docker run 8a135cfa`?  Since there could be multiple tags on the same image ID, Docker doesn't try to insert one?  It does look like your container is running on the image you expect at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted PyCharm support, and they were able to reproduce the issue. It seems like they have a bug with the new version.

Answer (score 2):

Two reasons I know of that docker will dereference the image name to an ID in the `docker ps` output:

1. You start the container using an image id rather than an image name. This could be done automatically by the tool you are using to launch containers. You can have multiple references pointing to the same ID, so there's no universal way to go backwards from an image ID to find the original image name you used to start the container.
2. The image reference you used to start the container now points to a different ID. This can happen if you remove a tag, change the destination of a tag, or pull a new version of an image. Containers run based on the image ID, so they will continue to run as is even if you pull a different image, and the image ID itself is immutable and cannot be deleted as long as you have a container using it.